# I can't start javadb in netbeans anymore

Tags: java, javadb

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/apache/derby/drda/NetworkServerControl Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Furthermore netbeans can't find

```
import javax.persistence.*;
```

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again ? I found this to be a very effective means of getting rid of netbeans errors

Comment: yes i have.
I'm working with a partner and we are using svn. Since we did the first commit and update for the database implementation my javadb isn't able to start anymore.